# How can I switch the positions of each element in a list with Python?

Tags: python

Using Python, what's the most efficient way to switch the positions of every other element in a list?

For example, I'm trying to get a sequential list of the alphabet with each letter after A switched, like so:

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
# ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

switched_alphabet = do_something_magic(alphabet)
# ACBEDGF... 
# position 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import string
>>> alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
>>> for i in range(2, len(alphabet), 2):
...     alphabet[i], alphabet[i-1] = alphabet[i-1], alphabet[i]
... 
>>> alphabet
['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'I', 'H', 'K', 'J', 'M', 'L', 'O', 'N', 'Q', 'P', 'S', 'R', 'U', 'T', 'W', 'V', 'Y', 'X', 'Z']
>>>
```

Comment: Huh, guess you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (using slices and much faster than `for` loop):

```
def switch(string, n=1):
    data = list(string)
    odd = -1 if (len(data)-n) % 2 else len(data)
    data[n:odd:2], data[n+1::2] = data[n+1::2], data[n:odd:2]
    return ''.join(data)

>>> switch(string.ascii_uppercase)
'ACBEDGFIHKJMLONQPSRUTWVYXZ'
```

`n` is the number of items you want to keep in order. There's a trick to handle strings with an odd length.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it might be done

Tools Used

[itertools.compress](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)

[itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

```
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
#The Even Series using itertools.compress
[x for x in itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[0,1]*(len(alphabet)/2))]
['C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S', 'U', 'W', 'Y']
#The Odd Series
[x for x in itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[1,0]*(len(alphabet)/2))]
['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
#Now Join it with itertools.izip
[''.join(x) for x in itertools.izip((x for x in itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[0,1]*(len(alphabet)/2))),
                                        (x for x in itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[1,0]*(len(alphabet)/2))))]
['CB', 'ED', 'GF', 'IH', 'KJ', 'ML', 'ON', 'QP', 'SR', 'UT', 'WV', 'YX']
#Finally Join as a Single String prefixing and 
#suffixing the first and the last character
alphabet[0]+''.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.izip((x for x in itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[0,1]*(len(alphabet)/2))),
                                                       (x for x in itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[1,0]*(len(alphabet)/2)))))
           +alphabet[-1]
'ACBEDGFIHKJMLONQPSRUTWVYXZ'
```

So the final solution is

```
alphabet[0]+
    ''.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.izip(
           itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[0,1]*(len(alphabet)/2)),
           itertools.compress(alphabet[1:],[1,0]*(len(alphabet)/2))))
           +alphabet[-1]
```

Note****

As @J.F.Sebastian pointed out, we can use [imap](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and that would simplify the above expression a bit

```
alphabet[0]+
"".join(itertools.imap("".join, itertools.izip(
           itertools.compress(alphabet[1:], itertools.cycle([0,1])), 
           itertools.compress(alphabet[1:], itertools.cycle([1,0]))))
           +alphabet[-1]
```

Comment: you don't need gencomp here: `"".join(imap("".join, izip(compress(A[1:], [0,1]*(len(A)//2)), compress(A[1:], [1,0]*(len(A)//2))))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Interesting, didn;t think it that way. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: you could also use `cycle([1,0])` instead of `[1,0]*(len(A)//2)`

Answer (score 1):

Internal indexes:

```
''.join(alphabet[i + (-1)**(i%2==0)] for i in xrange(1, len(alphabet)-1))
# -> CBEDGFIHKJMLONQPSRUTWVYX
```

The same -- using itertools:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

''.join(alphabet[i+j] for i,j in izip(xrange(1,len(alphabet)-1), cycle([1,-1])))
```

The first and last positions are left as an exercise.

Comment: @JBernardo: Are you sure that `(-1)**1` and `(-1)**0` are the bottleneck here?

Comment: Either that or indexing... The simplest for loop will be more readable and faster than that (with twice the indexing)